# XCode 4.6 app won't install via ipa to device

Tags: xcode

I have an app built in XCode 4.6 and I'm trying to install it onto an iPad with iOS 5.1.
In the target summary I have set the deployment target to 5.1 and in the build settings the base SDK is set to latest (6.1). From what I have read this should work but when I install the app via the IPA file and iTunes the app starts and then flashes off.
It runs fine if I build and install through Xcode.

Is there something I'm missing here? Am I incorrect in thinking it will work if the base SDK is iOS 6.1 but the deployment target is 5.1?

Comment: Check the device logs.  It's probably a provisioning issue.

Comment: but a provisioning issue would prevent it from installing at all wouldn't it?

Comment: The device logs are an excellent source of information. If you refuse to look there just because you think Kevin's guess might be wrong, you are saving your time but not ours. Have a look and let us know what you find. BTW: From the information you currently give, you are not doing anything fundamentally wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did double check the profile stored against the release configuration and found it was incorrect. So Kevin was  right. Thank you.
It had been my understanding up til now that a profile error would prevent installation altogether. I know better now.